# Ansible synchronize does not read ansible_sudo_pass variable

Tags: ansible

I cannot get Ansible's synchronize module to work. I have a very simple task:

```
- name: Copy project local files
  synchronize: src="{{ item.src }}"
               dest="{{ item.dest }}"
  with_items: project_local_files
```

When I execute `ansible-playbook playbook.yml --tags deploy --ask-su-pass --ask-pass`, all tasks go through. Then it stops at The synchronize task and prompts me for the password:

> admin@'s password:

I enter the password and then the task breaks with the following error message:

> msg: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

How can I synchronize files with Ansible's synchronize?

Comment: Try adding `pty=True` or un-comment line `pty=False` in your `ansible.cfg`.